# what is the default access modifer for java command line arguments

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

In other words using

```
main(String args[]) {
}
```

is args[] public, protected, or private?

Thanks

Comment: It's a method parameter.  Its scope is confined to `main`.

Comment: None of the above. Parameters don't have access modifiers. Not a real question.

Answer (score 6):

`args[]` is an argument to a function (which is `main`) and access modifiers are **not applicable** for arguments.

The arguments are always local to the functions for which they are being passed (That means their scope is, body of the function).

Access modifiers are applicable to all class members, including nested classes, enums, and interfaces.

```
public static void main(String [] args) ...
```

where `public` is the modifier for the method `main`

Comment: Essentially correct, but _"Access modifiers are only applicable for class properties and methods."_ is wrong. Access modifiers are applicable to all class members, including nested classes, enums, and interfaces. Package members (top-level classes, interfaces, and enums) can also be declared with `public` access or left with default (package-private) access. See the [Java Language Specification, §6.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6).

Comment: thank you @TedHopp, i have edited the answer, hope it is precise now

Answer (score 2):

Method arguments are essentially method-local variables; they do not have accessibility.